# Docker-compose setup script to set environment variables from within container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that will startup 6 different microservices. The way our docker-repository is setup prevents the use of the 'latest' tag so I am looking for a way to run a script before docker-compose pulls the microservice images, which will set environment variables in the scope of the docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  #Service 1
  svc1:
    image: some-snapshot.docker.privaterepo.com/some-service:${LATEST_SVC_TAG}
    container_name: service1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  #Service 2
  svc2:
    image: some-snapshot.docker.privaterepo.com/some-service2:${LATEST_SVC2_TAG}
    container_name: service2
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you really need "a script".  You can just run something like:

```
LATEST_SVC_TAG=1.1 LATEST_SVC2_TAG=2.5 docker-compose up -d
```

Alternately, you could place those into a `.env` file locally:

```
cat > .env <<EOF
LATEST_SVC_TAG=1.1
LATEST_SVC2_TAG=2.3
EOF

docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I need to be able to not hard-code the version numbers, and have this run on a CI server. i.e on a new push to master, pull down all the latest images for the other services and run some tests against them.

Comment: If you need this to run on your CI server, just make the versions parameters to your CI jobs and expose them into the CI environment. Or are you looking for a script that will *list all the available versions of your images, inspect the tags, and figure out which one is the most recent, and use that one*?